# Razones por la que el onActivityResult no este funcionando?

Tags: android, onactivityresult

les explico como esta mi problema resulta que estoy escaneando qr code les comparto mi codigo nada fuera de lo normal:

```
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    integrator.setPrompt("Scanea Codigo QR");
    integrator.setOrientationLocked(false);
    integrator.initiateScan();
```

el cual cuando termina de escanear debe entrar en el onActivityResult pero lo curioso es que me cierra el app y no marca ningun error

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult res = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    String contents;
    if (res != null) {
        contents = res.getContents();
        if (res.getContents() == null) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Se cancelo el escaneo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Se cancelo el escaneo", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

            switch (gv_coca.getState_scan()) {
                case 1:

                    Toast.makeText(this, "Scaneo normal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    try {
                        if (isConnectingToInternet()) {

                            CM_CC_ParametrosBusqueda cm_pabu = new CM_CC_ParametrosBusqueda();

                            cm_pabu.setId_cosecha(0);
                            cm_pabu.setId_alamcen(Integer.valueOf(contents));
                            cm_pabu.setCatacion("");
                            cm_pabu.setFechaInicio("31/12/9999");
                            cm_pabu.setFechaFinal("31/12/9999");
                            cm_pabu.setId_tipocatacion("");
                            cm_pabu.setId_origen("");

                            ImportaCatacion(cm_pabu);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:

                    Toast.makeText(this, "Scaneo Pesada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

aca les muestro lo que muestra en el RUN:

```
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:mx.com.ecc.controlcalidad time:668280696
I/DecodeHintManager: Hints from the Intent: {}
D/CameraPreview: resume()
D/CameraInstance: Opening camera
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x7f9e696c00 (AppCompatImageView) with handle 0x7f94976bc0
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@8515c15 time:668280943
D/CameraInstance: Configuring camera
I/CameraManager: Camera Display Orientation: 0
I/CameraManager: Initial camera parameters: preview-size=1920x1080;video-size=1920x1080;preferred-preview-size-for-video=1920x1080;preview-size-values=1920x1080,1280x720,720x480,640x480,352x288,320x240,176x144;video-size-values=3840x2160,2048x1536,1920x1080,1280x720,720x480,640x480,352x288,320x240,176x144;preview-format=yuv420sp;preview-format-values=yuv420p,yuv420sp;preview-frame-rate=30;preview-fps-range=1000,30000;preview-fps-range-values=(1000,15000),(15000,15000),(1000,30000),(30000,30000);preview-frame-rate-values=15,30;picture-size=3840x2160;picture-size-values=3840x2160,2048x1536,1920x1080,1280x720,720x480,640x480,352x288,320x240,176x144;picture-format=jpeg;picture-format-values=jpeg;jpeg-thumbnail-width=160;jpeg-thumbnail-height=90;jpeg-thumbnail-size-values=0x0,160x90,160x120;jpeg-thumbnail-quality=90;jpeg-quality=90;rotation=0;whitebalance=auto;whitebalance-values=auto,incandescent,fluorescent,daylight,cloudy-daylight;effect=none;effect-values=none,mono,negative,solarize,sepia,posterize;antibanding=auto;antibanding-values=off,auto,50hz,60hz;scene-mode=auto;scene-mode-values=auto,portrait,landscape,night,night-portrait,beach,snow,fireworks,sports,party,barcode,;flash-mode=off;flash-mode-values=off,auto,on,torch,red-eye;focus-mode=auto;focus-mode-values=infinity,auto,macro,continuous-picture,continuous-video;max-num-focus-areas=1;focus-areas=(0,0,0,0,0);focal-length=4.23;horizontal-view-angle=77.3672;vertical-view-angle=48.4809;exposure-compensation=0;max-exposure-compensation=6;min-exposure-compensation=-6;exposure-compensation-step=0.333333;auto-exposure-lock=false;auto-exposure-lock-supported=true;auto-whitebalance-lock=false;auto-whitebalance-lock-supported=true;max-num-metering-areas=1;metering-areas=(0,0,0,0,0);zoom=0;max-zoom=99;zoom-ratios=100,107,114,121,128,135,142,149,156,163,170,177,184,191,198,206,213,220,227,234,241,248,255,262,269,276,283,290,297,305,312,319,326,333,340,347,354,361,368,375,382,389,396,404,411,418,425,432,439,446,453,460,467,474,481,488,495,503,510,517,524,531,538,545,552,559,566,573,580,587,594,602,609,616,623,630,637,644,651,658,665,672,679,686,693,701,708,715,722,729,736,743,750,757,764,771,778,785,792,799;zoom-supported=true;smooth-zoom-supported=false;focus-distances=Infinity,Infinity,Infinity;max-num-detected-faces-hw=5;max-num-detected-faces-sw=0;video-frame-format=android-opaque;recording-hint=false;video-snapshot-supported=true;video-stabilization=false;video-stabilization-supported=false
I/CameraConfiguration: Requesting focus mode value from among: [auto]
Supported focus mode values: [infinity, auto, macro, continuous-picture, continuous-video]
Can set focus mode to: auto
Focus mode already set to auto
Requesting flash mode value from among: [off]
Supported flash mode values: [off, auto, on, torch, red-eye]
Can set flash mode to: off
Flash mode already set to off
I/PreviewScalingStrategy: Viewfinder size: 1184x720
I/PreviewScalingStrategy: Preview in order of preference: [1280x720, 1920x1080, 720x480, 640x480, 352x288, 320x240, 176x144]
I/CameraManager: Final camera parameters: video-size=1920x1080;preferred-preview-size-for-video=1920x1080;preview-size-values=1920x1080,1280x720,720x480,640x480,352x288,320x240,176x144;video-size-values=3840x2160,2048x1536,1920x1080,1280x720,720x480,640x480,352x288,320x240,176x144;preview-format=yuv420sp;preview-format-values=yuv420p,yuv420sp;preview-frame-rate=30;preview-fps-range=1000,30000;preview-fps-range-values=(1000,15000),(15000,15000),(1000,30000),(30000,30000);preview-frame-rate-values=15,30;picture-size=3840x2160;picture-size-values=3840x2160,2048x1536,1920x1080,1280x720,720x480,640x480,352x288,320x240,176x144;picture-format=jpeg;picture-format-values=jpeg;jpeg-thumbnail-width=160;jpeg-thumbnail-height=90;jpeg-thumbnail-size-values=0x0,160x90,160x120;jpeg-thumbnail-quality=90;jpeg-quality=90;rotation=0;whitebalance=auto;whitebalance-values=auto,incandescent,fluorescent,daylight,cloudy-daylight;effect=none;effect-values=none,mono,negative,solarize,sepia,posterize;antibanding=auto;antibanding-values=off,auto,50hz,60hz;scene-mode=auto;scene-mode-values=auto,portrait,landscape,night,night-portrait,beach,snow,fireworks,sports,party,barcode,;flash-mode=off;flash-mode-values=off,auto,on,torch,red-eye;focus-mode=auto;focus-mode-values=infinity,auto,macro,continuous-picture,continuous-video;max-num-focus-areas=1;focus-areas=(0,0,0,0,0);focal-length=4.23;horizontal-view-angle=77.3672;vertical-view-angle=48.4809;exposure-compensation=0;max-exposure-compensation=6;min-exposure-compensation=-6;exposure-compensation-step=0.333333;auto-exposure-lock=false;auto-exposure-lock-supported=true;auto-whitebalance-lock=false;auto-whitebalance-lock-supported=true;max-num-metering-areas=1;metering-areas=(0,0,0,0,0);zoom=0;max-zoom=99;zoom-ratios=100,107,114,121,128,135,142,149,156,163,170,177,184,191,198,206,213,220,227,234,241,248,255,262,269,276,283,290,297,305,312,319,326,333,340,347,354,361,368,375,382,389,396,404,411,418,425,432,439,446,453,460,467,474,481,488,495,503,510,517,524,531,538,545,552,559,566,573,580,587,594,602,609,616,623,630,637,644,651,658,665,672,679,686,693,701,708,715,722,729,736,743,750,757,764,771,778,785,792,799;zoom-supported=true;smooth-zoom-supported=false;focus-distances=Infinity,Infinity,Infinity;max-num-detected-faces-hw=5;max-num-detected-faces-sw=0;video-frame-format=android-opaque;recording-hint=false;video-snapshot-supported=true;video-stabilization=false;video-stabilization-supported=false;preview-size=1280x720
I/CenterCropStrategy: Preview: 1280x720; Scaled: 1280x720; Want: 1184x720
I/CameraPreview: Starting preview
D/CameraInstance: Starting preview
I/AutoFocusManager: Current focus mode 'auto'; use auto focus? true
D/DecoderThread: Found barcode in 35 ms
D/CameraPreview: pause()
D/CameraInstance: Closing camera
E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer could not be located....
E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer could not be located....
E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
D/CameraPreview: pause()
D/CameraPreview: pause()
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: reportFullscreenMode on inexistent InputConnection
W/MediaPlayer: mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
```

Comment: debugeaste si pasa por el onActivityResult()? puede ser que estes haciendo un finish() despues de ejecutar integrator.initiateScan(); ?

Comment: ya quedo.... era en el manifest en el activity tenia un propiedad que la tenia en false: 
    android:noHistory="true"